# Unable to populate opened email with subject and body

Tags: c#, .net, maui, mailto

I found two articles ([Open default mail client along with a attachment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20328598/open-default-mail-client-along-with-a-attachment) and [open an existing email with outlook from a website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8356301/open-an-existing-email-with-outlook-from-a-website)) which indicate using the "mailto" token allows passing the "subject" and "body" as parameters in the URL.  So far, this hasn't worked for me.  (NOTE: I'm trying to get this to work on the Android emulator and the email account is configured and working.)

I'm doing:

`await Launcher.OpenAsync($"mailto:{address}?subject:{subject}&body:{body}");`

After having populated appropriate variables.  It does open the Gmail app and opens a draft with the address in the "to".  But the "subject" and "body" are empty.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/email?tabs=android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MAUI, you can use the Email.ComposeAsync method:

```cs
var message = new EmailMessage
    {
        Subject = subject,
        Body = body,
        BodyFormat = EmailBodyFormat.PlainText,
        To = new List<string>(recipients)
    };

    await Email.Default.ComposeAsync(message);
```

Note that you need to add the "mailto" scheme to Android and iOS manifests. Please refer to [Email](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/communication/email?view=net-maui-7.0&tabs=android) for additional information.

Comment: Yes, the 'ComposeAsync()' threw the exception: "Microsoft.Maui.Essentials--Specified method is not supported" until I added the "package visibility requirement" for SENDTO.